# Question regarding $Z$ (Compressibility factor)

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

Oh! This problem has been bugging me for a long time. According to Wikipedia, the Compressibility factor $Z$ is defined as the ratio of the volume occupied by a real gas to the volume occupied by an ideal gas at the same temperature and pressure.

$$Z=\frac{V_{real}}{V_{ideal}} \text{              ........(1)} $$

Now the Ideal Gas Equation is

$$P_{ideal}V_{ideal}=nRT   \text{        ....(2)}$$
Now from here we can substitute the value of $V_{ideal}$ into the above expression $(1 )$ to get
$Z=\frac{PV_m}{RT}$
Where $V_m$ is the molar volume of the gas and $P$ is the value of $P_{ideal}$ that was in the ideal gas equation $(2)$.

OK, So far so good!

*Deriving the compressibility factor value from the van der Waals' gas equation:*

We know for real gases the pressure exerted by them is always less than the pressure exerted by an ideal gas so we correct the pressure by the term $a\frac{n^{2}}{V^{2}}$, we get

$$P_{ideal}=P_{real}+a\frac{n^{2}}{V^{2}}$$
And the volume occupied by the gas molecules can be written as

$$V_{ideal}=V_{real}−nb$$
On substituting the above values of $P_{ideal}$ and $V_{ideal}$ in the ideal gas equation, we get our *van der Waals'* Gas Equation

$$(P+a\frac{n^{2}}{V^{2}})(V−nb)=nRT$$
Please note that in the above equation $P$ is $P_{real}$ and not $P_{ideal}$. Now I'm going a step further to calculate the value of Z from this equation by shifting the terms and I got this
$$Z=\frac{PV_m}{RT}=\frac{V_m}{V_m−b}−\frac{a}{RTV_m}$$
Now here's the problem that I'm facing: *In the above expression the value of $P$ is not the $P_{ideal}$ but it is the value of $P_{real}$ that we had in the van der Waals' gas equation.*

Doesn't that contradict the whole definition of Compressibility factor that we had learned in the first place? How this expression for $Z$ can be correct?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/57909/102629

Comment: You may use \tag{N} for numbering equations, it would write right aligned  (N).

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the ideal gas.  The definition of the compressibility factor is just $$Z=\frac{PV_m}{RT}$$